# How to rename already registered category?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

How is it possible to rename default category name to custom name?

I want to rename default Category name to my custom name , I have used following  code but not work.

```
function wpse_modify_taxonomy() {
    // get the arguments of the already-registered taxonomy
    $people_category_args = get_taxonomy( 'category' ); // returns an object

    // make changes to the args
    // in this example there are three changes
    // again, note that it's an object
    $people_category_args->show_admin_column = true;
    $people_category_args->rewrite['slug'] = 'post';
    $people_category_args->rewrite['with_front'] = false;

    // re-register the taxonomy
    register_taxonomy( 'category', 'post', (array) $people_category_args );
}
// hook it up to 11 so that it overrides the original register_taxonomy function
add_action( 'init', 'wpse_modify_taxonomy', 11 );
```

Is anybody know how could this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can change the default category name to something else what ever you want.

First of all let's change the default label in the menu item in the WordPress admin. You can copy this code into your `functions.php` file

```
function revcon_change_cat_label() {
    global $submenu;
    $submenu['edit.php'][15][0] = 'MyCategories'; // Rename categories to MyCategories
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'revcon_change_cat_label' );
```

This will change Category name label in Menu items.

Now, let’s update the other labels throughout the admin (meta boxes etc.), you can paste this code directly below the code for renaming the menu label.

```
function revcon_change_cat_object() {
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    $labels = &$wp_taxonomies['category']->labels;
    $labels->name = 'MyCategories';
    $labels->singular_name = 'MyCategories';
    $labels->add_new = 'Add MyCategories';
    $labels->add_new_item = 'Add MyCategories';
    $labels->edit_item = 'Edit MyCategories';
    $labels->new_item = 'MyCategories';
    $labels->view_item = 'View MyCategories';
    $labels->search_items = 'Search MyCategories';
    $labels->not_found = 'No MyCategories found';
    $labels->not_found_in_trash = 'No MyCategories found in Trash';
    $labels->all_items = 'All MyCategories';
    $labels->menu_name = 'MyCategories';
    $labels->name_admin_bar = 'MyCategories';
}
add_action( 'init', 'revcon_change_cat_object' );
```

This way you can rename default category name to custom name.

Try it & let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code into your `functions.php` file.

Rename default Post Category Labels

```
// Rename default Post Category Labels
function rename_categories_function() {
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    $singular_name = 'New Categories Name';
    $plural_name = 'New Categories Names';
    $labels = array(
          'name'                    => $plural_name,
          'menu_name'               => $plural_name,
          'singular_name'           => $singular_name,
          'search_items'            => 'Search ' . $plural_name,
          'popular_items'           => 'Popular ' . $plural_name,
          'all_items'               => 'All ' . $plural_name,
          'parent_item'             => 'Parent ' . $singular_name,
          'parent_item_colon'       => 'Parent ' . $singular_name . ':',
          'edit_item'               => 'Edit ' . $singular_name,
          'view_item'               => 'View ' . $singular_name,
          'update_item'             => 'Update ' . $singular_name,
          'add_new_item'            => 'Add New ' . $singular_name,
          'new_item_name'           => 'New ' . $singular_name . ' Name',
          'add_or_remove_items'     => 'Add or remove ' . $plural_name,
          'back_to_items'           => '← Back to ' . $plural_name,
          'items_list_navigation'   => $plural_name . ' list navigation',
          'items_list'              => $plural_name . ' list',
     );    
    $wp_taxonomies['category']->labels = (object) array_merge( (array) $wp_taxonomies['category']->labels, $labels );
}
add_action( 'init', 'rename_categories_function');
```

Rename default Post Tag Labels

```
// Rename default Post Tag Labels   
function rename_post_tag_function() {
    global $wp_taxonomies;
    $singular_name = 'New Tags Name';
    $plural_name = 'New Tags Names';
    $labels = array(
          'name'                    => $plural_name,
          'menu_name'               => $plural_name,
          'singular_name'           => $singular_name,
          'search_items'            => 'Search ' . $plural_name,
          'popular_items'           => 'Popular ' . $plural_name,
          'all_items'               => 'All ' . $plural_name,
          'parent_item'             => null, // Tags aren't hierarchical
          'parent_item_colon'       => null,
          'edit_item'               => 'Edit ' . $singular_name,
          'view_item'               => 'View ' . $singular_name,
          'update_item'             => 'Update ' . $singular_name,
          'add_new_item'            => 'Add New ' . $singular_name,
          'new_item_name'           => 'New ' . $singular_name . ' Name',
          'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate ' . $plural_name . ' with commas',
          'add_or_remove_items'     => 'Add or remove ' . $plural_name,
          'back_to_items'           => '← Back to ' . $plural_name,
     );    
    $wp_taxonomies['post_tag']->labels = (object) array_merge( (array) $wp_taxonomies['post_tag']->labels, $labels );
}
add_action( 'init', 'rename_post_tag_function');
```

Enjoy

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).